# Traefik : Auto-add subdomains to cloudflare DNS

Tags: cloudflare, traefik

I use traefik as a reverse proxy for my self hosted services, and it works like a charm. Each time I add a new service, traefik detects it and routes queries accordingly. Each service is routed to a subdomain of my main domain.

The only manual step I still have to do is to add a new record in the DNS for my new subdomain. And I would like to automate it.

I know Cloudflare has an API for [managing DNS records](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record), and I can work it out from there. But I don't know if I can hook a script that would be triggered when traefik detects a new subdomain for example...

Any pointers on where I could investigate on the traefik side to detect the event that a new subdomain was added ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found a solution that answers my needs :

https://github.com/tiredofit/docker-traefik-cloudflare-companion

Internally it listens to the docker events and then re-checks all the running containers to detect if some tags have changed.

So the hook is not within traefik but rather directly within Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic DNS is taken care by [upload.express](https://upload.express/)

**Wildcard DNS records**

Alongside special case endorsements, almost all DNS suppliers support wildcard DNS records. By making an "A" section named "*.example.com", that focuses to your server's IP address, any solicitation that originate from any of your subdomain would divert to your server's IP. By doing this, you evacuate the need to execute your own space the board microservice.

You can also use the priorites explained in the Traefik Doc.

```
[frontends]
[frontends.frontend1]
backend = "backend1"
priority = 20
passHostHeader = true
[frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
rule = "PathPrefix:/to"
[frontends.frontend2]
backend = "backend2"
passHostHeader = true
[frontends.frontend2.routes.test_1]
rule = "PathPrefix:/toto"
```

Also we can do a Multi HTPS Sub Domain with Docker as explained [here](https://blog.ptrk.io/multi-https-sub-domain-with-traefik-and-docker/)

Comment: As stated quite clearly in the question, this is specifically about cloudflare, that does not support wildcard records for the free plan.

Comment: You could do it with Cloudflare & Lets Encrypt now that Lets Encrypt does wildcard certs. I'm currently doing this with my self hosted (non-Traefik) server. I have Cloudflare A and AAAA records of '*' that point to my server, the server has a *.example.com wildcard cert and this is used for all sub domains. Traefik can handle generating wildcard certs with Lets Encrypt https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tiredofit/docker-traefik-cloudflare-companion

This software has been updated to support A; AAA; CNAME is a DNS Record type, I think it is easier to use this tool than other

example

```
version: 3
services:
  cloudflare-companion:
    image: tiredofit/traefik-cloudflare-companion
    container_name: cloudflare-companion
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - TIMEZONE=America/Vancouver

      - LOG_TYPE=BOTH
      - LOG_LEVEL=INFO

      - TRAEFIK_VERSION=2
      - CF_EMAIL=email@example.com
      - CF_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - RC_TYPE=CNAME

      - TARGET_DOMAIN=host.example.org
      - DOMAIN1=example.org
      - DOMAIN1_ZONE_ID=1234567890
      #- DOCKER_HOST=tcp://198.51.100.32:2376
      #- DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/docker-certs
      #- DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

      #- TRAEFIK_FILTER_LABEL=traefik.constraint
      #- TRAEFIK_FILTER=proxy-public
    networks:
      - services
    restart: always

networks:
  services:
    external: true
```